# WPF datagrid update database

Tags: c#, wpf, database, datagrid, updates

I am pretty new in C#. I was writing a small GUI database application which uses a datagrid to show the table data. When I edit a row in the grid press the update button the update function of tableadapter is called and the change is propagated back to DB. Then I have implemented a handler for row changed event which in turns call the update function of tableadapter. But this time when some value is changed and enter key is pressed the handler is called and the InvalidOperationException is raised with the message "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." but the database is changed anyways. How to stop the exception to be raised. I have multiple active resultsets set to true in the connection string.

The constructor

```
public WSim(MainWindow h)
{
   InitializeComponent();

   //database connection with strongly typed dataset
   usersAdapter = new testDBDataSetTableAdapters.usersTableAdapter();
   users = usersAdapter.GetUsers();

   users.usersRowChanged +=new testDBDataSet.usersRowChangeEventHandler(users_usersRowChanged);

   this.DataContext = users.DefaultView;
}
```

The row changed event handler

```
private void users_usersRowChanged(object sender, testDBDataSet.usersRowChangeEvent e) 
{
    output.Content = "Row Modified";
    usersAdapter.Update(users);
}
```

The datagrid xaml

```
<DataGrid Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,249,0,0" Name="userGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="381" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
              SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow"  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True"
              CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says, you should close the reader first. You have not provided enough information and I cannot explain more; But See this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/08/20/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-must-be-closed-first-explained.aspx). I think it will help you.

Comment: But the problem is I am not manually opening any SQLDataReader. I have used the Data Source tool to add a new data source and it gave me a data set with its associated data adapters. I use the Get() method of the adapter to get the results in the table and use the Update method to update the database. So how should I control the datareaders

Comment: @SaifulShubho can you update your question and give us this method: `usersAdapter.Update(users);`.

Comment: I am not sure from where I can get the code as I am using a data source created by visual studio. But from the designer I got this query in the update method

Comment: UPDATE users SET userName = \@userName, password = \@password, Name = \@Name, Email = \@Email WHERE (userName = \@Original_userName)